# update multiple column in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have list of the column in single table which I want to update to some else.

Table name:HyundaiRaw_New_april

```
Original: 
HART 2008-A
HART 2009-A
HART 2010-A
HART 2010-B
HART 2011-A
HART 2011-B
HART 2011-C
HART 2012-A
HART 2012-B
HART 2012-C
HART 2013-A
```

I want the above thing to be updated as `'ABC 2008-A`'. I want HART to be replaced with "ABC"
I tried updating using the below query

```
update HyundaiRaw_New_april
set deal='HART 2009-A','HART 2010-A','HART 2010-B'
where DEAL='ABC 2009-A','ABC 2010-A','ABC 2010-B'
```

and

```
update HyundaiRaw_New_april
set deal=HART 2009-A,HART 2010-A,HART 2010-B
where DEAL=ABC 2009-A,ABC 2010-A,ABC 2010-B
```

it does not work

Comment: And **THAT**'s why you need to normalize your tables...

Comment: `set deal='HART 2009-A','HART 2010-A','HART 2010-B'` is invalid SQL

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
update 
  HyundaiRaw_New_april
set DEAL=REPLACE(DEAL, 'HART', 'ABC')
```

Comment: Sorry, the above query worked... how do you do when..its is all random alphabet, in this case it was "HART", how do you do?

Answer (score 0):

It should work for you...

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET COLUMNNAME = REPLACE(COLUMNNAME,'oldValue','newValue');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update HyundaiRaw_New_april
SET DEAL =  CASE WHEN DEAL = 'ABC 2009-A' THEN 'HART 2009-A'
                 WHEN DEAL = 'ABC 2010-A' THEN 'HART 2010-A'
                 WHEN DEAL = 'ABC 2010-B' THEN 'HART 2010-B'
            END
```

You also add a default value using `ELSE` clause in your CASE statement when no condition is met the column will be updated to default value mentioned in ELSE clause.